# Do you know a good open-source version-control viewer?

Tags: version-control, cvs, atlassian-fisheye

I'm looking for a tool like Atlassian's [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/). The alternatives I've found so far (like [StatCVS](http://statcvs.sourceforge.net/), [ViewCVS](http://www.viewvc.org/) or [Bonsai](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/bonsai/)) are either lacking in features or are quite a pain to install and maintain. So before staying with one of these tools, I'd like to be sure I did not miss any other good, easy to install, open-source (prefereably java) version control-viewer which supports cvs as scm.

Comment: Are we sticking with web-based tools here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) is a good open source, web based, repository viewer similar to FishEye. I know you've looked at it, and you're right, it was a hassle to set up, but once setup, it's run without any intervention for almost three years for us.

Answer (score 2):

Another SVN tool which has repository browsing capabilities is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). This is nice because as well as a browser for the repository it also has a timeline showing commits. It also does bug tracking.

Comment: Yes.. but he is looking for CVS tool.. not SVN...! Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[Warehouse](http://warehouseapp.com) is pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

There is also [CVS Monitor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cvsmonitor/), though it hasn't got the nearly the number of features as FishEye.

We use ViewCVS for repository browsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using SVN I'd highly recommend [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).

Comment: I'd really like to use svn. But for now, this is not my decision to make :-/

Comment: I know exactly what you mean; we're locked into using non-SVN source control for a lot or projects unfortunately! :-(

Comment: There's also Tortoise CVS (which I believe was the inspiration for Tortoise SVN).